# Codespaces devcontainer prebuild postCreateCommand uses sh instead of bash

Tags: vscode-devcontainer, codespaces, github-codespaces, devcontainer

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to get the prebuild `postCreateCommand` below to use bash instead of sh. We have this in our devcontainer.json:

`"postCreateCommand": "source /workspaces/devcontainer/init.sh"`

Which runs during prebuild stage, but fails with the following error:

`/bin/sh: 1: source: not found`

If the command is run with bash it works well, unfortunately my Linux (and devcontainer) knowledge is severely lacking so I don't even know where to really start. The image being used is the standard `mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal:linux` I've tried setting the `SHELL` env var to `/bin/bash`; replacing `source` with `.` stopped the source error, but unfortunately there are many other commands further into that shell script that really just need to be run with bash. Thanks so much